# Proving a matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Let $u_1,u_2,u_3$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Show that if a symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ satisfies $u_j^TAu_k=\delta_{jk}$ for $1\le j, k\le 3$ then $A$ is positive definite.

Attempt: $u_j^TAu_k=\delta_{jk}\ge 0$ and hence $A$ is positive definite.

Now I'm virtually certain this isn't a proof, mainly due to the length of it and also I haven't used many of the conditions in the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your definition of a matrix being  positive definite? [It is not that its entries are all non negative.]

Answer (score 1):

A matrix $A$ is positive definite if for **every** non-zero columnvector $z$ we have that $$z^T A z > 0.$$

You have only checked that the property holds for $z = u_i$.

Hint to complete your proof: what can you say about an arbitrary columnvector $v$ and its relation to the $u_i$? Remember, the $u_i$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$!

**EDIT:** as requested by OP:
You noted that any vector $v$ can be written as a linear combination of the basisvectors: $v = c_1 u_1 + c_2u_2 + c_3u_3$ for some real numbers $c_i$. This implies that
\begin{align}
v^TAv &= (c_1 u_1 + c_2u_2 + c_3u_3)^T A (c_1 u_1 + c_2u_2 + c_3u_3)\\
      &= c_1 u_1^TAc_1 u_1 + c_1 u_1^T A c_2 u_2 + c_1 u_1^T A c_3 u_3 + \ldots\\
      &= c_1^2 u_1^TAu_1 + c_1c_2 u_1^TAu_2 + c_1c_3 u_1^T A u_3 + \ldots \\
      &= c_1^2 \delta_{1,1} + c_1c_2 \delta_{1, 2} + c_1c_3 \delta_{1,3} + \ldots\\
      &= \ldots
\end{align}

If $v \neq \vec{0}$, at least one of the $c_i \neq 0$. What can you conclude from the computations? Can you clarify what happened in each line and take it from here? Fill in all dots (note that the amount of writing could be reduced using [capital-sigma notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation)).

Comment: Since the $u_i$ form a basis we can write $v$ as a linear combination - so $v=\alpha_1 v_1 +\alpha_2 v_2 +\alpha _3 v_3$. I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: Shouldn't it be a strict inequality in the definition of positve definite?

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht you're right, I'll edit.

Comment: @alidixon222: now with that expression, $v^TAv = \ldots$? Recall that multiplication is distributive!

Comment: @Student I'm really confused.... I can't seem to get anywhere with this

Comment: @alidixon222 i've added some of the computation which you should do. Fill in all details and try to justify each step.